# DCOM 10009 error for non-existent computer logged every 3 seconds

Tags: windows-server-2008, dcom

We have a Windows 2008 R2 Server with only SQL Server, AppAssure, and New Relic services running on it. An Event ID 10009 error is logged every 3 seconds:

> DCOM was unable to communicate with the computer {our domain name}
>   using any of the configured protocols.

Obviously, something is misconfigured somewhere. How can I find the source of the failing DCOM requests?

Comment: Google says: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asiatech/2010/03/15/how-to-troubleshoot-dcom-10009-error-logged-in-system-event/

Comment: @joeqwerty: I had seen that. But it assumes that the computer being referenced actually exists, which is not the case here. I need to find the source of the DCOM attempts, which that article does not address. Thanks for trying to help though.